# Different logo for sticky header in XTheme

Tags: jquery, sticky

I'm using this code to give me a different sticky logo when I start scrolling down the page.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.x-navbar').hasClass('x-navbar-fixed-top')) {
      $('.x-navbar-fixed-top .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/120?text=Secondary+Logo!');
    } else {
      $('.x-navbar .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/120?text=Original+Logo!');
    }
  });
});
```

It works fine, the only thing is that when I scroll back up the page, it doesn't change the logo back to the original logo. How can I tweak the code to show the original logo when I scroll back up to the top of the page?

Comment: Check if window.scrollY === 0 then reset the logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.scrollY`, the code will look something like this

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   if(window.scrollY === 0) {
     $('.x-navbar .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/120?text=Original+Logo!');
   }
   else
   {
    if ($('.x-navbar').hasClass('x-navbar-fixed-top')) {
      $('.x-navbar-fixed-top .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/120?text=Secondary+Logo!');
    } else {
      $('.x-navbar .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/120?text=Original+Logo!');
    }
   }
  });
});
```